# The input view's bottom border look different in iOS webview

Tags: css, ios, webview, uiwebview

It seems that in ios webview, the bottom border of the input form somehow become like U shape

[image]

Can I make it looks like in android using css?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this css reset for inputs

```
 border-radius: 0;
 font-family: inherit;
 font-size: inherit;
 color: inherit;
 box-shadow: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
```

Comment: why "border: none"? Remove it then I will accept your answer.